# Retrieve textboxdata in "" (double code)

Tags: c#, regex

```
var regex = new Regex(".*T120(.*)SAOE.*");
```

I wrote this function for getting string between this two word i.e. `T120` and `SAOE` and this function works well. I want to accept this value from user. What should I do? I want string between two words and words are accepted by user.

Comment: *works well. I want to accept this values from user* --  What does that mean ?

Comment: Just a note: you do not need outer `.*`, use `var regex = new Regex("T120(.*?)SAOE", RegexOptions.Singleline);` (`.*?` to match the shortest substring between the first `T120` till the closest `SAOE` and `RegexOptions.Singleline` so as to match across newlines).